# setState being set to last element of array onClick regardless of element targeted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looping through an array to render values. I need to grab the value and setState when I click on an item. Right now, regardless of what element I click on, it sets the state to the value of the last element in the array.

I think the issue may be that I am using an arrow function in the call for the onClick. The jslint also highlights a bad practice about calling a function in a loop like this.

You can click on any of the values and the state will get stringified at the bottom. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
     currentValue: null,
    }
  }
  
  getValue = (valueToGet) => {
   this.setState({
     currentValue: valueToGet,
    })
  };
  
  render() {
 const Values = {
     valuesList: [{
        value: 'value one'
        },{
        value: 'value two',
        },{
        value: 'value three',
        }
      ]
    };
    
    var renderValues = [];
    var valuesList = Values.valuesList;
    
    for(var i=0; i < valuesList.length; i++) {
     var valueItem = valuesList[i];
      
      renderValues.push(
      <div 
        onClick={() => this.getValue(valueItem.value)}
        key={i}
      >
        <p>{valueItem.value}</p>
      </div>
      )
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {renderValues}
        {JSON.stringify(this.state.currentValue)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
}

p {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of traditional `for` loop, you can make use of [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over the array.

```
 renderValues = Values.valuesList.map((valueItem,i) => {
      return <div 
        onClick={() => this.getValue(valueItem.value)}
        key={i}
      >
        <p>{valueItem.value}</p>
      </div>
    })
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5yyjue)

Comment: This is great. Thank you. I dont use map that often. Do you know why calling the arrow function onClick inside map doesn't cause the same issue that it does in the for loop?

Comment: Callback in map creates its own scope on every iteration.

Comment: Also check this - https://medium.com/front-end-developers/es6-variable-scopes-in-loops-with-closure-9cde7a198744. Reading this you will have clear idea of `var` and `let`.

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely correct in pointing out that the problem lies in the functions created in the loop. A closure is being created when you define the function in the loop and the last value passed in the closure is of third value which is shown for all the onClick functions.

The detailed explanation can be found [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-loop-func)

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions and for the helpful link.

Answer (score 1):

Arrow function in a loop isn't the problem but containing unsafe variable `valueItem` of it is.

Using `let` instead of `var` for the variable `valueItem` makes your code work.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
     currentValue: null,
    }
  }
  
  getValue = (valueToGet) => {
   this.setState({
     currentValue: valueToGet,
    })
  };
  
  render() {
 const Values = {
     valuesList: [{
        value: 'value one'
        },{
        value: 'value two',
        },{
        value: 'value three',
        }
      ]
    };
    
    var renderValues = [];
    var valuesList = Values.valuesList;
    
    for(var i=0; i < valuesList.length; i++) {
     let valueItem = valuesList[i];
      
      renderValues.push(
      <div 
        onClick={() => this.getValue(valueItem.value)}
        key={i}
      >
        <p>{valueItem.value}</p>
      </div>
      )
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {renderValues}
        {JSON.stringify(this.state.currentValue)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
}

p {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```